# How can I analzye only specific sentences in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, text-analysis

I have a data set of 4,500 long texts that I analyze using R packages. I want to analyze only sentences that contain specific words, how can I do it? and can I use R to create a second set of all the sentences (which will be independent of the original set?)
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data:

```
lorem <- "\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,\nsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi\nut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit\nin voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur\nsint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit\nanim id est laborum.\n\nSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque\nlaudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi\narchitecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas\nsit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione\nvoluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,\nconsectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et\ndolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum\nexercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi\nconsequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam\nnihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?\n"
```

Write it as a single text file "lorem_ipsum.txt"

```
cat(lorem, file="lorem_ipsum.txt")
lorem <- readLines("lorem_ipsum.txt")
```

To return only lines that contain the word "lit"

```
output<-grep("lit", lorem, value=T)
output

[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,"                                
[2] "in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur"                
[3] "sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit"          
[4] "consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et"
[5] "consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam"
```

Delete the "lorem_ipsum.txt" file

```
unlink("lorem_ipsum.txt")
```